# How to replace the dependent variable in a formula?

Tags: string, r, formula

Suppose I have an R formula such that:

```
fm <- formula(y~x1+x2+x1:x2)
```

And a set of new response outcomes, `y1`, `y2`, `y3`. How could I replace the `y` in the formula `fm` through a `for` loop?

```
for (newy in c(y1,y2,y3)){
    newfm=formula(...)
}
```

Comment: May you give an answer using the example?

Comment: Can you take a look first and see if you can figure out how it helps you solve your own problem?

Comment: The thing I'm frustrating is the interaction term in the original formula and how to index it to `reformulate` arguments.

Comment: look at `terms(fm)` to get the indices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
fm <- formula(y~x1+x2+x1:x2)
for (newy in c("y1","y2","y3")){
    newfm <- reformulate(deparse(fm[[3]]),response=newy)
    print(newfm)
}
## y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
## y2 ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
## y3 ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2
```

Handling formulas as formulas is admittedly a little tricky -- it's actually easier to handle them as characters and then use `reformulate` or `as.formula`.

It would be interesting but considerably trickier to do this in the way suggested by the OP, using symbols rather than characters in the `for` loop -- i.e. `for (newy in c(y1,y2,y3))` because the symbols would somehow have to be intercepted before R tried to evaluate them (and threw an error).  I can't see how to make any construction of the form

```
for (newy in c(y1,y2,y3)) {
    ...
}
```

work, because R will try to evaluate `c(y1,y2,y3)` before it enters the for loop ...

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    as.formula(paste0("y",i,"~x1+x2+x1:x2"))
}
```

Comment: why do you need `stringi::stri_paste` for this?  What's wrong with `paste0` from base R?