# How to dynamically build a multivariate formula in R?

Tags: r

I have some data like those:

```
train <- data.frame(x1 = c(1.5,2,-2), x2 = c(2,11,3), x3 = c(8,3,4), y1 = c(3,4,9), y2 = c(8,5,3))
test <- data.frame(x1 = c(10,4,2), x2 = c(8,3,5), x3 = c(6,4,20), y1 = c(9,1,2), y2 = c(0,9,8))
```

I have a model like this one, everything works as expected:

```
model_formula <- as.formula(cbind(y1, y2) ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
model <- lm(model_formula, data = train)
predictions <- predict(model, newdata = test)
> predictions
         y1       y2
1 -9.859375 16.71875
2 -0.937500 10.87500
3  2.781250  7.437
```

However, for some reason, I find it impossible to generate the formula dynamically. When I build some strings like those

```
predictors <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
predictors_str <- paste(predictors, collapse = " + ")

responses <- c("y2", "y2")
responses_str <- paste(responses, collapse = " + ")
```

and build a formula out them, I don't get the same results :/

```
model_formula <- reformulate(termlabels = predictors_str, response = responses_str)
# or by 
model_formula <- as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ %s', responses_str, predictors_str))
```

I now get something different:

```
model <- lm(model_formula, data = train)
predictions <- predict(model, newdata = test)
Warning message:
In predict.lm(model, newdata = test) :
  prediction from rank-deficient fit; attr(*, "non-estim") has doubtful cases
> predictions
      1       2       3 
33.4375 21.7500 14.8750
```

This is not a two-dimensional response any more. I believe the reason is that I somehow have to include cbind() into the formula as above, but how?

There are plenty of posts on Stackoverflow (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820396/how-to-replace-the-dependent-variable-in-a-formula) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820396/how-to-replace-the-dependent-variable-in-a-formula) one) on building formulas dynamically, but at least in this multivariate case (two responses) I have found none that works for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129225/combining-cbind-and-paste-in-linear-model

Comment: Should look more like this: `predictors <- c("x1", "x2", "x3"); responses <- c("y2", "y1"); model_formula <- reformulate(termlabels = paste(predictors, collapse = " + "), response = paste0("cbind(", paste(responses, collapse = ", "), ")"))`

Comment: Thanks! That works. Too bad that I didn't see this post. But even now, knowing that it exists, I don't find it on Google with search terms like "r replace formula multiple multivariate site:stackoverflow.com". So even though this is a duplicate maybe it spares to other people the three hours I spent on this.